# Data type for storing latitude and longitude in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geolocation

I want to store latitude and longitude in oracle db. Which data type its good to use it for both these fields. I really appreciate for your reply.

```
"latitude": 48.858844300000001,
"longitude": 2.2943506,
```

Comment: Try with geometry and polygon as point also works

Comment: Can you please give me a reference, how to define/retrieve this field from table.

Comment: NUMBER comes to mind. Any reason to think otherwise?

Comment: In postgresql the data types are there with additional his plugin.try searching plugin for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Each column would be `NUMBER(x+3,x)` where x is the maximum number of decimal places you would ever wish to store (48.858844300000001 is VERY precise).

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE cola_markets ( mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(32), shape SDO_GEOMETRY);

And for point

> CREATE TYPE sdo_point_type AS OBJECT ( X NUMBER, Y NUMBER, Z NUMBER); CREATE TYPE sdo_elem_info_array AS VARRAY (1048576) of NUMBER; CREATE TYPE sdo_ordinate_array AS VARRAY (1048576) of NUMBER;

For inserting and select queries please read Oracle document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm)

Comment: so, how we should insert and select the data here

Comment: Be aware that Oracle [Spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b28004/xe_locator.htm#CIHFBGJG) Data is an [enterprise edition cost option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877.pdf).

Comment: @PremanandK See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34872681/1509264) for an example of inserting and querying data using Oracle's spatial data.